# Save .txt file into a Azure Blob storage

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

With an Ubuntu VM I have downloaded and unzipped several .txt files that I would like to save as Azure blob storage (one for each file), in a way that I can use them with Spark.
Is there any way to do that form ssh or azure portal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Azure CLI to upload your files: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-azure-cli/

Comment: Finally I got it. I am uploading the files to blobs. Thank you very much! Just one question: it is normal that the speed is just 3.5MB/s on average? I thought that cloud internal data-transfer would be much faster!